# Reverse index in CQL

Tags: cassandra, cql

Currently, I have two tables like this:

```
create table id_to_name (
  userid uuid,
  name_id int,
  name text,
  PRIMARY KEY(userid, name_id) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (name_id)   
);

create table name_to_id (
  userid uuid,
  name text,
  name_id int,
  PRIMARY KEY(userid, name) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (name)   
);
```

(We have a particular use case why name_id is int instead of uuid).

I need to select the name via the name_id and the name_id via the name.  Is there a way I can do this efficiently in a single table?

If not, and we made name_id auto incrementing, is there a way we can guarantee that they would match across tables?  Is a trigger our best bet?

Answer (score 1):

There's no auto-incrementing in Cassandra that I'm aware of.  That is why uuid's were invented, so that each node could assign unique values without colliding with values assigned by other nodes.

Also I thought triggers in Cassandra were somewhat experimental, so I haven't used them.

So I think you are stuck with two tables.  When you update one, you need to update the other (usually using a batch statement).

In the longer term this type of use case will be supported by materialized views.  You would create one table as the base table and then define the second table as a view.  Cassandra would then take care of maintaining the view automatically when you update the base table.  This will be available in 3.0, which is in alpha release at this point.